# (no code yet) How to make multiple cart sessions on each store

Tags: cart, customer-session, multiple

Correct me if I am wrong: for multiple cart sessions you multiply the store front. But how to allow a customer to manage multiple carts for a given store?

EDIT: Discussing with Fabian, two ideas emerge:

- add to cart button prompts (pop-in) the choice to add to a cart from a list -manageable from customer/account
- only one cart at a time, save cart for later use as a quotation (from customer/account: manage multiple quotations)

  scenarii

  ```
  cart -> checkout
  cart -> quote
  cart -> quote1 ; cart -> quote2 ; quote1 -> cart -> checkout
  ```

  this second idea is a bit like the module "save for later" or "cart2quote", but the objective is not to save A list of products but many lists.

I am just at the beginning of the thinking, so no code **yet**.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How should this work process-side? Does the user has different carts and then you can change them? This could be done via different quotes with different IDs and only one of them are is active.

Comment: I suppose so, but I did not find anyone handling more than one quote at a time.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Please edit your question and describe how the user should handle this. How to change quote or do you have all, all the time? How to know, in which quote the product should be added, or which quote to checkout? In one sentence WHAT DO YOU WANNA ACHIEVE? Please edit your question to answer these questions.